# aiohttp: client.get() returns html tag rather than file

Tags: python, aiohttp, tarfile

I'm trying to downloads bounding box files (stored as gzipped tar archives) from image-net.org. When I `print(resp.read())`, rather than a stream of bytes representing the archive, I get the HTML `b'<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=/downloads/bbox/bbox/[wnid].tar.gz" />\n` where `[wnid]` refers to a particular wordnet identification string. This leads to the error `tarfile.ReadError: file could not be opened successfully`. Any thoughts on what exactly is the issue and/or how to fix it? Code is below (`images` is a `pandas` data frame).

```
def get_boxes(images, nthreads=1000):

    def parse_xml(xml):
        return 0

    def read_tar(data, wnid):
        bytes = io.BytesIO(data)
        tar = tarfile.open(fileobj=bytes)
        return 0

    async def fetch_boxes(wnid, client):
        url = ('http://www.image-net.org/api/download/imagenet.bbox.'
            'synset?wnid={}').format(wnid)
        async with client.get(url) as resp:
            res = await loop.run_in_executor(executor, read_tar,
                await resp.read(), wnid)
            return res

    async def main():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession(loop=loop) as client:
            tasks = [asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_boxes(wnid, client))
                for wnid in images['wnid'].unique()]
            return await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(nthreads)
    shapes, boxes = zip(*loop.run_until_complete(main()))
    return pd.concat(shapes, axis=0), pd.concat(boxes, axis=0)
```

EDIT: I understand now that this is a [meta refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) used as a redirect. Would this be considered a "bug" in `aiohttp?

Comment: IMO meta refresh is not part of HTTP, HTTP client library doesn't need to support it necessarily

Comment: Seems reasonable, but I admit I'm a newbie to http clients. Either way, since the redirects take a predictable from I can just request them directly.

Answer (score 1):

This is ok.

Some services have redirects from user-friendly web-page to a zip-file. Sometimes it is implemented using HTTP status (301 or 302, see example below) or using page with meta tag that contains redirect like in your example.

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://www.iana.org/domains/example/
```

`aiohttp` can handle first case - automatically (when `allow_redirects = True` by default).
But in the second case library retrieves simple HTML and can't handle that automatically.

Comment: @dezmond-goff, did I answer your question or something else is left?

Answer (score 1):

I run into the same problem \n
when I tried to download using wget from the same url as you did
http://www.image-net.org/api/download/imagenet.bbox.synset?wnid=n01729322

but it works if you input this directly
www.image-net.org/downloads/bbox/bbox/n01729322.tar.gz

ps. n01729322 is the wnid